# Possible to create a temporary host entry on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Is it somehow possible to edit /etc/hosts on Heroku , through the buildpack or otherwise?

I have a couple of dev sites that I need to connect to that don't have DNS entries, so I need to add a couple entries to /etc/hosts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that's not possible. However, why can't you just specify the IP of whatever host you're trying to connect to, instead of specifying a host name? Also, if you absolutely must, I suppose you could create entries in a DNS server of a domain of your own (say: `mydomain.com`), and then specify `myhost.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Thanks can't use just the IP address, its name based shared host. No worries. I 'll just make some real dns entries, but thats a pain in the ass for temporary sites.